# Sort using sub-arrays

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Problem: Hey, I'm trying to create a website that ranks certain submissions by having users submit their own work and then ranking five other submissions from best to worst.

My Attempt:
I've simulated this where the submissions are numbers from 0-num of submissions and then I introduce some human error by taking a sorted array and making 1, 2, 3 or 4 swaps at 75% 50%, 25% and 12% probability. My first attempt at an algorithm is as follows. We split the array into 5 sub arrays, then we sort each sub array based on the amount of times each number has already been sorted and pick the smallest picked number in each subarray. Then I sort those with my simulated error and put them back in their correct indexes.

For example if I had the inital array as (format num:times_been_sorted)

[1:0, 11:0, 29:0, 7:0, 0:0, 21:0, 2:0, 27:0, 25:0, 28:0, 22:0, 5:0, 4:0, 14:0, 10:0, 20:0]

And picked the following indices based on the split of 5 and each numbers history
[0, 3, 6, 9, 12]

My initial sub array is this
[1:0, 7:0, 2:0, 28:0, 4:0]

My sorted sub array is this
[1:0, 2:0, 4:0, 7:0, 28:0]

And my new array is this
[1:1, 11:0, 29:0, 2:1, 9:0, 0:0, 21:0, 4:1, 27:0, 25:0, 7:1, 22:0, 5:0, 28:1, 14:0, 10:0, 20:0]

I've come up with this completely on my own, so I'm sure theres room to improve or another algorithim entirely that can be used and hasn't come up in my research. I'd really appreciate any sort of guidance. Thank you!

Edit:

My code for this simulation is here:

```
from random import randrange
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import randrange
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
class Submission:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num 
        self.picks = 0

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.num) + ":" + str(self.picks)

def select_idx(arr):
    idxs = []
    top = int(len(arr) / subarray_size)

    for i in range(subarray_size):
        sort = sorted(range(top * i, top * (i + 1)), key=lambda k: arr[k].picks)
        idxs.append(sort[0])

    return idxs

def sort_w_error(arr, err):
    sort = sorted(arr, key=lambda x: x.num)
    rand = random.uniform(0, 1)
    if err: 
        if rand < 0.75:
            sort = swap(sort, randrange(len(arr)), randrange(len(arr)))
            if rand < 0.5:
                sort = swap(sort, randrange(len(arr)), randrange(len(arr)))
                if rand < 0.25:
                    sort = swap(sort, randrange(len(arr)), randrange(len(arr)))
                    if rand < 0.12:
                        sort = swap(sort, randrange(len(arr)), randrange(len(arr)))
    
    return sort

n = 400
subarray_size = 5
submissions_entries = random.sample(range(n), n)
submissions = []
for submission in submissions_entries:
    submissions.insert(randrange(len(submissions) + 1), Submission(submission))
    if len(submissions) > subarray_size:
        random_idxs = select_idx(submissions)
        random_arr = []
        for idx in random_idxs:
            random_arr.append(submissions[idx])
        sort_arr = sort_w_error(random_arr, False)
        sorted_idxs = sorted(random_idxs, key=lambda x: x)
        for i, idx in enumerate(sorted_idxs):
            submissions[idx] = sort_arr[i]
            submissions[idx].picks = submissions[idx].picks + 1
print(submissions)

for idx, submission in enumerate(submissions):
    if submission.picks <= 1:
        plt.plot(idx, submission.num, 'b.')
    elif submission.picks <= 3:
        plt.plot(idx, submission.num, 'c.')
    elif submission.picks <= 5:
        plt.plot(idx, submission.num, 'g.')
    elif submission.picks <= 7:
        plt.plot(idx, submission.num, 'r.')
    else:
        plt.plot(idx, submission.num, 'k.')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Please post your code as well.

Comment: You can use a list of tuples or maybe a numpy array of tuples. numpy makes slicing pretty easy and sorting a list of tuples can be done using the sort method. You can use a lambda function to tell python how and according to which element the tuples shall be sorted

Comment: I'm not sure my question was understood well, my goal is to sort using only the information of multiple mini 5 element sub array sorts. This should somehow sort the main array. @alexschu98

Comment: To make sure I understood correctly: You have your array of tuples (num, times_sorted). You slice this array in five sub arrays and sort each of them according to times_sorted. You pick the element with the lowest times_sorted value from each of these five subarrays and put them in a new array. This new array gets some random swaps based on the probabilities you gave in your post. The new sorted array is copied back into the original array at the original indices. Did I get this right?

Comment: Yes, this is my current approach. However, it doesn't seem to work very well and I was wondering how I could improve it or if there was another algorithm I could use to make it better.

Comment: You could take a look at elo systems (e. g. chess). Of course you would need to extend this to multiple players. A simple approach to this would be the following: Someone just rated five comissions. They have the elos A: 2000, B: 1800, C: 1600, D: 1400 and E: 1000. The persons rank them B, C, A, D, E. You treat this like B has beaten C and update them accordingly. Same goes for C and A, A and D and finally D and E. This would cross out the "times already rated"-thing out of your approach.

Comment: Oh I have no idea how I didn't consider a performance rating like chess! Thank you so much for the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're still interested in using an elo system I have some straight-forward code for you:

```py
class EloSystem:
    def __init__(self, K=32):
        self.K = K # K factor which gives the max change in the elo number
        self.Players = dict() # empty dict using player name as uniqe id

    def addPlayer(self, name, elo=1500):
        self.Players[name] = elo

    def getWinProbability(self, PlayerA, PlayerB):
        p = (self.Players[PlayerB] - self.Players[PlayerA]) / 400.0
        E = 1.0 / (1.0 + 10**(p))
        return E

    def updatePlayerElo(self, Winner, Loser):
        E = self.getWinProbability(Winner, Loser)
        self.Players[Winner] += self.K * (1.0 - E)
        self.Players[Loser] -= self.K * (1.0 - E)
```

I guess this is pretty self explanatory.